# Evaluating booleans from strpos() in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean, strpos

This is my code,

```
  $em= strpos($str, 'something');
  $em2= strpos($str, 'something2');
  $em3= strpos($str, 'something3');
////////triggering only if either of them exist

  if (($em!== false)||($em2!== false)||($em3!== false)) {
  some action
  }
```

Is my coding correct? or I am missing anything?
Please suggest.

Should it be like     ?

```
 if (!(($em== false)||($em2== false)||($em3 == false))) {
```

Comment: That depends on what you want to test.

Comment: Either of them or at least one?

Comment: any of them, bu the looks of it

Comment: PHP if statement ||? - this in not meaningful question(title)

Answer (score 2):

To check if `strpos()` did not find any occurence of the substring you need to use `===` (which compares the value *and* the type) because `strpos()` may also return `0` which evaluates to `false` when compared with `==`.

**Edit:** The author edited his question. This answer covers the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are checking for a boolean, you should always use `===` or `!==`.

The main reason for that is in PHP, `$Test == 1` or `$Test == TRUE` or `($Test)` is the same if the value of $Test is not empty.

About your parantheses. If you have more then 1 logic to apply, use them, if not, optional.

```
if($Test === TRUE OR $Foo === TRUE){

}
```

and

```
if($Test === TRUE OR ($Foo === TRUE AND $Bar === TRUE)){

}
```

Also, instead of using `||` or `&&` to check for `TRUE` or `FALSE`, use `OR` or `AND` against a boolean.

Comment: since Abul uses `$em= strpos($str, 'something');` you might also want to explain to him why he should then cast $em to make sure it's a boolean...

Comment: Because later I will use those $em positions for my functions.

Comment: @AbulHasnat Timothy is a bit right. This function return not only `FALSE` but also the real position in the string (`INTEGER`). If you cast the function as a `BOOL`, it will either be `FALSE` or `TRUE`. In this case, `TRUE` will be `$em >= 1`.

Answer (score 0):

some of your parentheses (`( )`) aren't necesary but it should work like this.

```
if (!($em=== false || $em2=== false || $em3 === false)) {
       // do something
}
```

Comment: Make sure to use `===`, `0 == false` is true.

Answer (score 0):

Both the cases give the same result. What is your intention is not correctly mentioned. Are you getting any error here?

You can find more at http://www.phpsyntax.blogspot.in

Answer (score 0):

if you search something,something2,something3 in a text which is in $str it's ok.

but if you thought to find a string from $str in something,something2 or something3 it's here the issue.

you should have a look at this php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

regards